# head :ok valid for a :js response?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of items. A user can click a button to add new items. They can also delete existing items. Sometimes those items are saved and sometimes those items are unsaved. So if they are unsaved, I don't want to pass javascript back to browser to be executed. I just want to do nothing. So I figured to do this:

```
  def destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      @line_item = LineItem.find_by_id(params[:id])
      if @line_item.present?
        @line_item_id = @line_item.id
        @line_item.destroy

        format.js
      else
        format.js { head :ok }
      end
    end
  end
```

I know that `head :ok` simply passes back the response headers to the browser with a blank space as the body. If this was a `:json` response, this would be a problem because javascript client code would raise an exception when trying to parse that blank space as json. However, in the event that the response is `:js`, would this be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought was to see what [JSON:API](http://jsonapi.org/) recommended for something like a `DELETE` request that didn't need to return any content. (*Somewhat* similar to your situation.)

[From their spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-deleting):

> #### 204 No Content
>
> A server **MUST** return a `204 No Content` status code if a deletion request is successful and no content is returned.

So it seems like perhaps the best course of action would be this:

```
head :no_content
```

You'll want to see how your the client reacts to receiving a `204` response, but it should likely be accepted as an OK-like response because it is in the 200 series.